# Is there a .isHidden function for an array?

Tags: ios, swift

Basically other objects on Swift like button or something else have an .isHidden value to hide the object or not. I'm wondering if I can do that with an array.

Comment: From what do you want to hide the array? A way to "hide" an object in code is an appropriate scope.

Comment: not that I know of. I think it would be better if you create a `struct` that has 2 members, one of `bool` type and the other of type `array` and then manage accessing the `array` based on the value of the `bool`

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Please update your question clarifying what you mean by "hiding" an array. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @rmaddy I have an array that holds movies and I want to hide them when the user searches for a specific movie, right now I'm using .removeAll() but then I have to call the fetchJSON function again.

Comment: Please update your question with these clarifications so people see all relevant details in your question. And provide some context. Is this for a table view? For a search controller?

Comment: No it's a collection view, so I'm calling the movieurl ex: url.json?queryterm="searched movie" and then displaying them on the collection view.

Answer (score 3):

An array is a data structure and not a graphical element, and as such can't be hidden.

According to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622585-ishidden) .isHidden is a member of the UIView class, which an array is not.

I think the more interesting question is why would you want to hide an array? Swift has automatic memory management so if the array is no longer needed the System will dispose of it as required.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your array and hide each element in turn:

```
for view in views {
    view.isHidden = true
}
```